# How to reshape dataframe, wide to long, for several variables in one or several calls?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've been unable to reshape the below dataframe into the long format:

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [66602088802, 85002620928],
     't1': ['car', 'house'],
     't1_pct': [0.46, 0.51],
     't1_valid': [True, True],
     't2': ['bike', 'car'],
     't2_pct': [0.15, 0.07],
     't2_valid': [True, True],
     't3': ['car', 'toy'],
     't3_pct': [0.06, 0.07],
     't3_valid': [False, False]})

    id               t1     t1_pct  t1_valid t2  t2_pct t2_valid    t3  t3_pct  t3_valid
0   66602088802     car     0.46    True    bike    0.15    True    car     0.06    False
1   85002620928     house   0.51    True    car     0.07    True    toy     0.07    False
```

My desired outcome is below. I've attempted to use `pandas.wide_to_long()` but so far no luck. Thanks in advance.

```
    id         test  value     pct     valid
66602088802    1      car     0.46     True
85002620928    1      house   0.51     True
66602088802    2      bike    0.15     True
85002620928    2      car     0.07     True
66602088802    3      car     0.06     False
85002620928    3      toy     0.07     False
```

Thank you in advance.

pandas 0.23.4

python 3.7.1

Comment: please look into multiindex dataframe and stack unstack commands. Please let me know if you can't figure it out and I will give you a detailed answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `wide_to_long`; the issue is just that your column names need to be changed a bit, so that the stubnames are `['pct', 'valid', 'value']`, and not `t#`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Reverse order of words around '_'
df.columns = ['_'.join(x.split('_')[::-1]) for x in df.columns]
# Add prefix for other stubs
df = df.rename(columns= dict((f't{i}', f'value_t{i}') for i in np.arange(1,4,1)))

pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['pct', 'valid', 'value'], 
                i='id', j='test', suffix='.*', sep='_').reset_index()
```

#### Output:

```
            id test   pct  valid  value
0  66602088802   t1  0.46   True    car
1  85002620928   t1  0.51   True  house
2  66602088802   t2  0.15   True   bike
3  85002620928   t2  0.07   True    car
4  66602088802   t3  0.06  False    car
5  85002620928   t3  0.07  False    toy
```

Comment: thanks I'm getting me head around wide_to_long the above is also really helpful

Comment: I have never thought of swapping words in column names to use `wide_to_long` :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I do not think wide_to_long can reshape to what you need , you can check with `melt`

```
s=df.melt('id')
s=pd.concat([s,s.variable.str.split('_',expand=True)],1).fillna('value')
s.set_index(['id',0,1]).value.unstack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'text'})
1           id text   pct  valid  value
0  66602088802   t1  0.46   True    car
1  66602088802   t2  0.15   True   bike
2  66602088802   t3  0.06  False    car
3  85002620928   t1  0.51   True  house
4  85002620928   t2  0.07   True    car
5  85002620928   t3  0.07  False    toy
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question; this answer may be helpful to new visitors looking for an alternative.

This answer borrows from @ALollz's solution of renaming the columns before reshaping.

You can use the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html):

```
import re
 # pip install janitor
 # you could also install latest dev version
 # pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
import pandas as pd
(
    df.rename(columns=lambda column: f"{column}_value" 
                                     if re.match("t\d$", column) 
                                     else column)
      .pivot_longer(index="id", 
                    names_to=("temp", ".value"), 
                    names_sep="_")
      .drop(columns="temp")
)

          id    value   pct     valid
0   66602088802 car     0.46    True
1   85002620928 house   0.51    True
2   66602088802 bike    0.15    True
3   85002620928 car     0.07    True
4   66602088802 car     0.06    False
5   85002620928 toy     0.07    False
```

If you are certain that your data order is consistent(t1, t1_pct, t1_valid, t2, t2_pct, ...), you can use that order to reshape the data, via regular expressions:

```py
    df.pivot_longer(index = 'id', 
                    names_to = ['value', 'pct', 'valid'], 
                    names_pattern = ['t\d$', '.*_(pct)$', '.*_(valid)$'])
    
                id  value   pct  valid
    0  66602088802    car  0.46   True
    1  85002620928  house  0.51   True
    2  66602088802   bike  0.15   True
    3  85002620928    car  0.07   True
    4  66602088802    car  0.06  False
    5  85002620928    toy  0.07  False
```

You could also use the `.value` placeholder along with a regular expression :

```py
(df
.pivot_longer(
    'id', 
    names_to = '.value', 
    names_pattern = r"t\d_?(.*)")
.rename(columns={'':'value'})
)

            id  value   pct  valid
0  66602088802    car  0.46   True
1  85002620928  house  0.51   True
2  66602088802   bike  0.15   True
3  85002620928    car  0.07   True
4  66602088802    car  0.06  False
5  85002620928    toy  0.07  False
```